# CountDownLatch with a dynamic timeout

Tags: java, synchronization, countdown, countdownlatch

I am using a CountDownLatch to wait for N operations to complete before executing some code, whilst giving a timeout to make sure that the final code gets executed even if not all N operations are completed.
i.e:

```
    CountDownLatch latch= new CountDownLatch(N);
    latch.await(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    //Some code
```

I would like the 20 minutes timeout to be dynamic, so that it is reset each time the latch gets a countdown, so the latch will exit the await only if 20 minutes has passed since the last time it got a countdown (or the normal case ofcourse, when it recieves N countdowns). Is this supported in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this feature in your own `CountDownLatch`. You can keep a timestamp of when the method `countDown()` is called, compare it to the timestamp when the waiting was started, adjust the waiting time and wait again if the timestamps are different. For example,

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class MyCountDownLatch extends CountDownLatch {
    private AtomicLong timestamp;

    public MyCountDownLatch(int count) {
        super(count);
        timestamp = new AtomicLong(System.nanoTime());
    }

    @Override
    public void countDown() {
        super.countDown();
        timestamp.set(System.nanoTime());
    }

    public boolean waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = timestamp.get();
        long diff = 0;
        for (;;) {
            boolean result = await(unit.toNanos(timeout) - diff, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            if (timestamp.get() == start) return result;
            start = timestamp.get();
            diff = System.nanoTime() - start;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a test program:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyCountDownLatch latch = new MyCountDownLatch(3);

        // Create three workers and give them different work time
        Worker worker1 = new Worker("A", 1, latch);
        Worker worker2 = new Worker("B", 3, latch);
        Worker worker3 = new Worker("C", 5, latch);
        List<Worker> workers = Arrays.asList(worker1, worker2, worker3);

        // Start the workers
        workers.forEach(Worker::start);

        // Wait until the latch to count down to zero, or no countdown in
        // 3 seconds.
        boolean result = latch.waitFor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.printf("%s | latch.waitFor() returns %b\n", LocalTime.now(), result);

        // Terminate those workers who are still running
        workers.stream().filter(Worker::isAlive).forEach(Worker::interrupt);
    }


    static class Worker extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private int workTime;
        private CountDownLatch latch;

        public Worker(String name, int workTime, CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.name = name;
            this.workTime = workTime;
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s | Worker %s started\n", LocalTime.now(), name);
                Thread.sleep(workTime * 1000L);
                System.out.printf("%s | Worker %s finished\n", LocalTime.now(), name);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.printf("%s | Worker %s interrupted\n", LocalTime.now(), name);
            } finally {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }
}
```